# Problem with superscript-style numerical citation call-outs with natbib

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

My problem is the following. I want my citations to be numerical and superscripted. They also should be sorted according to their appearance in the text. With the following script, I only get two citations working and the rest is simply marked with "?". I use BibTex with MacOS.

```
\usepackage[super, numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
...
\begin{document}
...
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{Quellen.bib} 
\end{document}
```

This is the warning:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `good_2013a' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "should be sorted after their appearance in the reference list". Do you maybe mean, sorted in ascending order (so that the bib items are sorted according to their first citation in the body of the document)? BTW, the options `super` and `numbers` are mutually exclusive. You should delete the `numbers` option in order to assure that you'll get superscript-style citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico They should be sorted according to their first citation in the document. I deleted the 'numbers' but I still only get 2 superscripted citations

Comment: Then it is probably `unsrtnat.bst`

Comment: You need to (a) switch the argument of `\bibliographystyle` (from `abbrvnat` to `unsrtnat`, as @daleif has suggested as well), (b) make sure that you load `natbib` without the option `numbers`, and (c) perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. (Of course, the entry with key `good_2013a` must be in the bib file, but I am assuming that you've already made sure that this is indeed the case.)

Comment: I tried what you told me, but it still only shows question-marks instead of the numbers in the text. When I tried the full recompile cycle, not even my 2 working citations show. Now I only get question-marks. 
I'm quite sure, that there should be an easy solution for this. But I'm new to LaTeX and I don't know what I could try next

Comment: And I also want them to be abbreviated. Is that possible? When I remember correctly, when I use unsrtnat, then they are not abbreviated